# React-Native resize emoji and text size in TextInput together

Tags: react-native, emoji, textinput

I want to resize text with emoji in TextInput, only text works well but when insert emoji not.

```
const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(16);
const input = useRef(null);

// resize Input func
const onFontSizeChange = () => {
    setFontSize(fontSize + 5);

    input.current.setNativeProps({
      style: {
        fontSize: fontSize + 5, 
      },
    });

}

<TextInput 
    ref={input}
    multiline={true} 
    style={{fontSize: 16}}
    forceStrutHeight={true}  
    value={textValue}
    onChangeText={typedText => {
        validate(typedText);
    }}
/>
```

How to I do this?

Comment: When is onFontSizeChange called?

Comment: When I finish typing text, then on click TouchableOpacity => this call onFontSizeChange func

Answer (score 0):

Just use a state object as style and mutate the style object when you click the button.

```
const [style, setStyle] = useState({ fontSize: 16})

const onButtonClick = () => {
    setStyle({ fontSize: 20, lineHeight: 23 })
}

<TextInput 
    multiline={true} 
    style={style}
    forceStrutHeight={true}  
    value={textValue}
    onChangeText={typedText => {
        validate(typedText);
    }}
/>
```

Comment: What means `forceStrutHeight `?

Comment: Weird, it does work when I tried to reproduce the problem. Take a look at this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@jurrian-l/da603a)

Comment: [emoij input resize snack](https://snack.expo.io/@jurrian-l/emoij-input-resize)