# React Native: Change text and emoji fontSize in TextInput on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, textinput

There is a problem on the `TextInput` which contains `text` and `emoji` together and try to resize them or change `color/fontSize`  by other component (not manually) .

Resizing, changing `color` and `fontSize` of `TextInput`'s content works only without `emoji`.

Can you help how to resolve `TextInput` problem (described above) with text+emoji content?

I don't have this problem with Android.

`allowFontScaling={false}` => Didn't helped me.

React Native version: 0.61.5

Comment: please share your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917257/react-native-resize-emoji-and-text-size-in-textinput-together it's my code

Comment: https://github.com/sskhandek/react-native-emoji-input
did you try this module?

Comment: nope, I use keyboard defaults emoji